# PHP + Mysql: dynamic table name from first query for execution of second query

Tags: php, mysql, join, dynamic

I have three tables, the first is a table storing applications, the second is a table storing different online forms (different types of applications), the third is a table that stores actual form data:

```
    TABLE applications=========
    -applicationID (PK)
    -formID (FK)
    -formRecordID
    ====================  

    TABLE forms=========
    -formID (PK)
    -formName
    -tableName (could be 'form_businessLicense','eventLicense',etc)
    ====================

    TABLE form_businessLicense=====
    -recordID (PK)
    -dateSubmitted
    -(a whole bunch of other data)
    ===============================
```

"formRecordID" points to "recordID" in "form_businessLicense" or "eventLicense". Since it could reference any table, it can't be a foreign key. So instead I grab the tableName from the "forms" table, then build a query to get all the application data from, say "form_businessLicense".

So I need to get data from, say, all applications plus a bit of data from the application form filled out (ex:form_businessLicense). I'm just going to paste my code (I'm actually querying all applications in a given set of IDs):

```
$applications = $this->selectAll(
            "SELECT applicationID, formName, tableName, fieldIdentifier, formRecordID, dateSubmitted, DATE_FORMAT(dateSubmitted,'%c/%e/%Y') AS dateSubmittedFormat
            FROM applications AS a 
            JOIN forms AS f
            ON a.formID = f.formID
            WHERE a.applicationID IN (".$applicationIDs.")
            ORDER BY dateSubmitted ASC"
        );

        for($a=0;$a<count($applications);$a++){
            $form = $this->select("SELECT ".$applications[$a]['fieldIdentifier']." AS identifierName
                FROM ".$applications[$a]['tableName']."
                WHERE recordID = ".$applications[$a]['formRecordID']
            );
            $applications[$a]['identifierName'] = $form['identifierName'];
        }
```

Is there any way to merge these two queries into one so I don't have to loop over all results and run a separate query for each result? I feel like I could maybe do this with a JOIN but I'm not sure how to reference the "tableName" and "formRecordID" for use in the same SQL statement.

Comment: How many different `form_*` tables are there?

Comment: Why are you using a for loop and not a simple while/foreach. What about you first get a list of table names and id's and then you make an inner join and get all data at once!

Comment: It's usually a good design decision to merge all of these dynamically named tables into one generic table. You can then filter and search much easier and wont have any such problems. Such dynamically generated table names, probably with identical structures usually arent a good design decision.

Comment: If your tables all have different columns (probably containing different form's data) you might want to switch to a EAV model. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model I run that in MySQL and it works nicely.

Comment: There are 5 tables total - each very, very different from the other.EAV is a good suggestion - I probably would have taken that approach if the tables were to be dynamic - but because of budget (and the client is the IT dept - capable of dealing with the database directly if needed) we thought it faster to go this approach. @sirwilliam, do you have an example for an inner join for me?

Comment: what about an union, it might make more sense than a join if you need data from several tables

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply join to three tables, and select count(PK) of third table while adding a group by clause for the PK of third table.

**Note:** PK used for Primary Key